# How to configure a compiler in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-construction, qt-creator

I have tried to compile some C++ code in Qt Creator, however I am getting this error message:

> :-1: error: Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure a
>   compiler in the kit options.

How do I go about configuring a compiler in the kit options?

Comment: You need to configure a compiler in the kit options.

Comment: When there's not even a question mark used in posting the question, I wonder how much effort's been made in investigating the issue.

Comment: Can you post how you set up the sdk and on what environment (operating system) you're using.

Comment: Please provide screenshots about your trial so that we can see what you have set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-targets.html) is a link to the Qt documentation that talks about adding kits. 
and [Here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23013)  is a similar question asked in the Qt forums.

Comment: @user3119614 *How* does it not work?  What error messages are you receiving, what is the current configuration, etc.?  We're not psychic.

Comment: the same message that always comes